# Which pipe server is selected when we launch multiple instances of the same application that uses WCF net pipe to communicate?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, named-pipes

Assume we have an application A. It has two modules that it loads Module X and Module Y which communicate via net.pipe and a fixed URI.

Say Module X (WCF client) connects to Module Y(WCF server) with URI MyService. Also note there could be multiple instances of Module X in the same app that connect to Module Y.
Now if we launch another instance of the application A, we will have two named pipe server instances with same URI created by Module Y. (The search algorithm used by WCF named pipes is listed [here.](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/10/20/locating-a-wcf-named-pipe-endpoint.aspx))

Which pipe will be used by the modules to connect to each other if multiple instances of the same application is launched?

Answer (score 0):

> we will have two named pipe server instances with same URI created by
>   Module Y

I don't think this is possible, because only one ServiceHost at a time can open a listener on a specific net.pipe URI, as far as I know, so you could only have one named pipe server active on the URI at any one time.

If you think you have succeeded in creating multiple concurrent active servers, please edit your question to be more specific about the service hosting, and what you mean by "Application" and "Module" and "instances" thereof.

Comment: I did not go into specifics. All I did was launch the same application twice. The second application did not throw an error. So I assumed that both the application were able to create a WCF named pipe instance with same name. Also I am using WPF application that internally uses WCF named pipes to communicate between different modules (which are all inside the same process).

Comment: The reason I was looking into this was: 1. I wanted to understand the effects of using hardcoded URI on applications that allow multiple instances to be launched. 2. I was reading your blog post on WCF named pipe security and was looking at spoofing attack that can be launched by already opening a WCF port which corresponds to same URI as the application and wanted to know if that is feasible